# Efficiency of Calculating with Different Data Types?

Tags: sql, performance, sql-server-2005, optimization, types

I have a 1.2 billion row data set that involves columns of high precision floating point/decimal numbers. The requirements are that we have accuracy out to about 12 decimal places. I do not need to compare for perfect equality and I do not need to prevent weird numeric artifacts (like 7 coming out as 7.000000000000001).

So, this project could use either FLOAT or DECIMAL(18,15)... Or maybe DECIMAL(15,12) if there were a reason to. Calculations I will need to do with this data involve ABS(), AVG(), addition, subtraction, multiplication, and division. Possibly also other statistical functions.

Which, if any, of the data type options would be most efficient for this task?

EDIT: Here is some test code I am trying to use to answer this. But I keep getting an arithmatic overflow error. Not sure how to avoid it without mucking up the test by changing data types. Does anyone see what I can cast, without introducing data types that invalidate this test? Code follows:

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#TempFloat') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #TempFloat
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#TempDecimal') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #TempDecimal
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#TempBinary') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #TempBinary

SELECT CAST(RAND() AS FLOAT) AS RandA, CAST(0 AS FLOAT) AS CalcA INTO #TempFloat 
SELECT CAST(RAND() AS DECIMAL(18,15)) AS RandA, CAST(0 AS DECIMAL(18,15)) AS CalcA INTO #TempDecimal
SELECT CAST(RAND() AS BINARY(8)) AS RandA, CAST(0 AS BINARY(8)) AS CalcA INTO #TempBinary

INSERT INTO #TempFloat
(
    RandA,
    CalcA
)
(
SELECT 
    CAST(RAND() AS FLOAT) AS RandA, 
    CAST(0 AS FLOAT) AS CalcA
)

INSERT INTO #TempDecimal
(
    RandA,
    CalcA
)
(
SELECT 
    CAST(RAND() AS FLOAT) AS RandA, 
    CAST(0 AS FLOAT) AS CalcA
)

INSERT INTO #TempBinary
(
    RandA,
    CalcA
)
(
SELECT 
    CAST(RAND() AS FLOAT) AS RandA, 
    CAST(0 AS FLOAT) AS CalcA
)
GO  -- 9999

UPDATE #TempFloat
SET CalcA = (ABS((RandA/2) - 1) * 10000) + (RandA - (RandA * 2))

UPDATE #TempDecimal
SET CalcA = (ABS((RandA/2) - 1) * 10000) + (RandA - (RandA * 2))

UPDATE #TempBinary
SET CalcA = (ABS((RandA/2) - 1) * 10000) + (RandA - (RandA * 2))
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why not try a few different ways and measure the performance? (On a subset of the data, of course.) I suspect it will come down to two main factors 1) the specific RDBMS (which should be included in the tag); 2) the ability of the RDBMS to use native floating-point operations without need for intermediate guards or conversions

Comment: What is the incoming datatype? I would normally match that.

Comment: Must the dataset be human-readable? Nobody's going to read 10^9 numbers. If it's in the form of double-precision binary, each number will take 8 bytes, and reading the data will be at hardware speed, with full 17-digit precision.

Comment: How often are you doing calculations versus reading in the data?  For most SQL queries, the overhead of reading and writing pages far outweighs numeric processing considerations.

Comment: @user2246674, I've attempted to test this for FLOAT, DECIMAL, and BINARY(8). The code of my test, and a problem implementing it is now in the post above.

Comment: Cool. What did the initial benchmarks show? (Also, don't forget to tag the question with the appropriate RDBMS vendor/versions.)

Comment: @user2246674, Thanks. I've added the tag. I didn't know what that meant the first time. As for benchmarks, I have not gotten that test code to run without using casts that I think will muddy it up. Of course, if casts are just necessary, they wouldn't be mud. Will update if I learn more.

Comment: A note on the arithmetic overflow issue. My guess is it is the `#TempDecimal` table where it occurs and the problem is, the column that you are trying to update cannot hold values of `1000` and greater (the whole part can consist of no more than 18-15=3 digits) while the expression you are using in the UPDATE statement *can* result in such a value.

Answer (score 0):

As a rule of thumb, expect faster calculations with doubles than with numerics or decimals. Arbitrary-precision math is expensive. Floating-point math on modern computers is relatively cheap. (Am I the only one who remembers having to buy a floating-point processor to speed up spreadsheet calculations?)

But that's a rule of thumb. If you have lots of rows, lots of columns, and *relatively* few digits  in your numeric or decimal types, you *might* find that disk I/O is the bottleneck. (PostgreSQL supports up to 1000 digits of precision in numeric data types. I'd call that relatively *many* digits.)

The best thing you can do for your company is to

- build a test table that's identical in structure to your production table, and
- load it with enough rows of random data that it won't fit into RAM.

Then run and time a set of queries to test the performance.

Use a test table that's identical to production, because having a lot of columns exercises the disk subsystem differently than having few columns. Use a *lot* of random data, because you want to try to approximate the behavior of the troublesome table.  (Testing with narrow tables, like you're doing in your test code, won't sufficiently stress the system.)

If this table is financially significant, it's probably worth reading your dbms's documentation for the CREATE TABLE statement. You'll almost certainly find several options that can significantly affect performance. Oracle's CREATE TABLE statement documentation takes about 50 pages to print on paper. (50, not a typo.)